How is ब्राह्मण supposed to be pronounced?
English speakers say "Brahmin".  Indians usually say "Brahmana" (Hindi speakers would omit the final "a").  I have also heard "Bramhana" from some priests. Does scripture suggest that pronunciation?

In Sanskrit, each syllable is fully pronunced unlike Hindi. It's BrAmhaNa. Some pronunce the ha before the ma. https://www.reddit.com/r/sanskrit/comments/1dk8pd3/pronunciation_of_hma/
